# checing if index of Dynamic Array is empty?

Tags: c++, arrays

ho to check if some index of dynamic array is empty or not?

```
string *array = new string [size];
...some code
while(array[index] != NULL) //this gives error 
    i++;
```

thanks..

Comment: An array doesn't have "empty" elements. So you can't check if an element is empty.

Comment: By the way, there's an algorithm `std::find_if_not` to find the first element that doesn't satisfy a predicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `string` in your code is just an `std::string`, use [string::empty](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/empty/).

For default-constructed `string`, `empty()` will always return true. If you want to clear string at some point, use [string::clear](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/clear/). After calling `clear()`, `empty()` will always return true.

So, your code should look like this:

```
string *array = new string [size];
...some code
while(!array[index].empty())
    i++;
```

Note, that you don't check if 'index is empty' - `array` is an array of strings, so all 'slots' contain valid string objects. You can only check if some of these objects are empty or not - and that's what this code is doing.